# Getting "Maximum call stack size exceeded" with this and $in in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I'm getting `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` when I try to use `$in` and `this` in a *pre* *remove* middleware in Mongoose 5.

I don't get this error if I use `.where` and `.in` with `this`.

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    blogPosts: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'blogPost'
    }],
});

UserSchema.pre('remove', async function() {
    const BlogPost = mongoose.model('blogPost');

    //This line throws the RangeError
    await BlogPost.deleteMany({ _id: { $in: this.blogPosts } });

    //This one works
    await BlogPost.deleteMany().where('_id').in(this.blogPosts);
});
```

I am doing something wrong here?

**Edit:**
The Problem occurs inside the model file when using `this`, if I try to `console.log` `this` I get this error, or, in this case, `this.blogPosts` when using with `$in`.

**Edit 2:**
While debbuging the source code I found the reason why I'm getting this error.

It is because my `BlogPost` schema also has a reference to `User`. It loads the `User`, then the `User` loads the `BlogPost`, then the `BlogPost` loads the `User`, and so on, until the maximum call stack is exceeded.

I just don't know why it happens only in some cases, like the first `deleteMany` call.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in my *app.js* file.

I created an example function that was performing every crud operation.

It was doing something like this:

```
const user = new User({...
const blogPost = new BlogPost({...

//saving, updating and retrieving...

user.remove();
```

The last line was causing the error, so I replaced the `user.remove()` with the following code:

```
const doc = User.findOne({});

doc.remove();
```

Now everything works.

It is weird that calling `remove()` using the same reference as the *new* model was causing this issue.

Comment: did it take one month to find the issue?

Comment: It was a study project of mine, I was only working on it once a week. And I was looking for the problem in the wrong place aswell.

Comment: just kidding @jonas, Happy coding